# Custom TabLayout android error when add tab to mTabs

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I make my custom tablayout view to customize font for tablayout android but it give me crash on mTabs.add(position, tab); what is wrong with my code?

```
@Override
public void addTab(@NonNull Tab tab, int position, boolean setSelected) {
    MyTextView myTextView = (MyTextView)
    View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.tab_item_template, null);
    myTextView.setText(tab.getText());
    tab.setCustomView(myTextView);

    mTabs.add(position, tab);
    super.addTab(tab, position, setSelected);
}
```

the error is

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to set custom tabs in your tab layout

```
TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabOne.setText("ONE");
tabOne.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent));
tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);// if you want to set icon on that tab
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
```

Comment: not fixes error is on mTabs.add(position, tab); when i comment it. tablayout works fine but i cant change color of text and everything else

Comment: It doesn't depend on TextView, I said when I want to add tab to ArrayList it makes error that ArrayList is empty and index 10 is out of bound